# What Javascript code is required to convert a lead to account

Tags: javascript

I want my agents to be able to convert a lead to an account from the lead list view. I have created the custom button but need the appropriate code. I used what was suggested but get a message Missing ; Before startement

Can anyone help me correct this?

Thanks 
Emerson

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stackexchange! Please edit your question and include the code which you are using, so that we can help you!

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript syntax error. Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would have approached this solution

1) Create a global apex class
2) Define a static webservice method with logic to convert the lead
3) call the method from javascript

The apex class would look something like this

```
global class convertLead{
    WebService static void convertLeadtoAcc(string id){
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(id);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel 
                                    FROM LeadStatus 
                                    WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];                
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    }
}
```

Now use the javascript to call this method

`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}` 
`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}`
`sforce.apex.execute("convertLead","convertLeadtoAcc", {id:"{!Lead.Id}"});`

Ofcourse you might want to bulkify the methods to process multiple leads at a time. However the basic idea would be the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll have to combine 2 functionalities.

[`GETRECORDIDS`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#GETRECORDIDS) to fetch ids of records for which checkbox was ticked in the listview. (Caveat: last time I had to use it it didn't work in iSafari).

It's unclear whether you want to use visualforce / apex webservice or would you rather stay within pure JS solution... Since you struggle with JS syntax error I'd recommend involving apex like in @Modem's answer. In future maintenance it's more likely that another developer will understand Apex but his JS skills might be not as good.

But - for the sake of completeness. As far as I know whole SOAP API is implemented (exposed?) in the AJAX toolkit. So the [`convertLead()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_convertlead.htm) call is available too.

Here's the [example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm):

```
var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
account.Name = "convert lead sample";
account.Phone = "2837484894";
result = sforce.connection.create([account]);
account.Id = result[0].id;

var lead = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
lead.Country = "US";
lead.Description = "This is a description";
lead.Email = "someone@somewhere.com";
lead.FirstName = "first";
lead.LastName = "last";
lead.Company = account.Name;
result = sforce.connection.create([lead]);
lead.Id = result[0].id;

var convert = new sforce.LeadConvert();
convert.accountId = account.Id;
convert.leadId = lead.Id;
convert.convertedStatus = "Qualified";

result = sforce.connection.convertLead([convert]);
if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
  log("lead converted " + result[0]);
} else {
  log("lead convert failed " + result[0]);
}
```